# Непредвиденное появление cmd

Tags: mysql, bat, резервное-копирование

Батник содержит:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('wmic path win32_LocalTime get DayOfWeek') do set wd=%%i

if %wd%==1 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup1.sql)

if %wd%==2 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup2.sql) 

if %wd%==3 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup3.sql) 

if %wd%==4 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup4.sql) 

if %wd%==5 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup5.sql) 

if %wd%==6 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup6.sql)

if %wd%==7 (F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup7.sql)
```

Т.е каждый день недели он создает разный бекап из Mysql

Ошибка:

```
Непредвиденное появление(F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump)
```

Comment: set file=%SYSTEMROOT%\setupact.log
    If Exist %file% For %%i In (%file%) Do SET TIMESTAMP=%%~ti
    F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup\%timestamp:~0,10%.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка из-за `%wd%==n` нужно экранировать `"%wd%"=="n"`. 
И вообще, зачем условия?

```
@echo off
For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [1-7]') Do (Set wd=%%#)
F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > "backup%wd%.sql"
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать